# ETag not being returned by WebResponse Header in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-headers, etag

I am trying to extract the ETag from the response header.  It does exist in the response.  I can see it using firebug and I can see it in the response object using the inspector:

```
Status: 200 OK
X-Api-Version: 1.3.2
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Runtime: 0.151298
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 8185
Cache-Control: public, max-age=11216
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 09 Mar 2012 01:40:05 GMT
Expires: Fri, 09 Mar 2012 04:47:01 GMT
ETag: "bd3fe1123a8f55e01ca859f4804e8fbe"
Last-Modified: Fri, 09 Mar 2012 00:47:01 GMT
Server: nginx/1.0.11
```

All the other code is working fine, making the HttpWebRequest, getting the respose etc.  The only problem is I always get null when trying to get the ETag (which does existing in the response header).

Here is the simplified code:

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(validUri);
        SetHeaders(); // helper function to set basic headers.
        var response = request.GetResponse();

        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

        var etag = response.Headers.Get("ETag");
```

Anyone know why I can't seem to extract the existing ETag?

Comment: What inspector are you referring to? Is it possible that the header is returned to the browser, but not to your code?

Comment: @zespri code break - inspect response variable.

Comment: @zespri the browser is not being used - only called from code.

Comment: How can you use firebug without a browser? I thought it's a browser plug-in?

Comment: @zespri used firebug as a secondary confirmation that the ETag is in the response. When running the code above, I am only running the client - also confirmed the ETag is in the response via inspecting 'response'.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not reproduce the problem you are describing. Your problem is in something that you have not mentioned. Here is a short *complete* program based on your code, that executes and does print out the value of ETag without a problem:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace SO9628006
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Fiddler.css");
            var response = request.GetResponse();

            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var etag = response.Headers.Get("ETag");

            Console.WriteLine(etag);

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"6c3673ba919ec71:243"
```

Could you please provide [short but complete program](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html) that illustrates your issue?